# Can I use desktop PC's power supply to power up SATA-to-USB cable?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, power-supply

My desktop PC's mainboard is dead. Since I already have 2 laptops at home, fixing the PC is not a priority.

I need to connect the HDDs (3.5" SATA) from the old PC to the laptop time to time, to pull some old data or to backup unused data from the laptop. For that purpose, I bought a SATA-USB converter cable along with it's power adapter.

The cables are working fine, but not the power adapter. I've bought same thing twice from different brands, but it's always the power adapter that's failing.

Now looking at my old PC, I'm thinking: if I use the PC's power supply to power up the HDD and use the converter cable to connect it to the laptop, it should work. Right?

My question is:
1. Is it really possible to use my method above?
2. Is it safe for the data on the HDD?
3. If its possible, then I sould be able to connect more than 1 HDD to the same power supply, right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 1: Yes, you can because after all it's the PC's power supply. Its output voltage on the 4-pin molex connector is the same as the external power adapter.

Question 3: And of-course you can connect that many HDDs, that you have ports on the supply.

Question 2: It's totally safe if the power supply is working correctly.

But the problem is it turns on only when it is connected to a PC, but the hack is you have to connect the green wire coming out from the supply to the any black ground wire.

See *[How to Power Up an ATX Power Supply Without a PC!](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-power-up-an-ATX-Power-Supply-without-a-PC/step2/Connect/)*.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked the fact that it is built for a PC, therefore it powers up using the power button on the PC's case. I've read the instructable, and it seems safe enough provided I follow the correct steps. Thanks